# xbacklight not working on Debian Jessie, lenovo S10

Tags: xorg, backlight, i915

I'm trying to change the backlight via xbacklight but this is not working. Although

```
xbacklight -set X
```

causes

```
xbacklight -get
```

to return X, the real monitor backlight is unchanged.

The XF86MonBrightnessDown (fn+some-key) isn't working either, although it may have been working earlier.

How can I further debug this issue?

I tried stracing the xbacklight call, I'm including the output, but I can't make anything out of it.

Is there a way to do this via xrandr or is there a lower-level way?

```
execve("/usr/bin/xbacklight", ["xbacklight", "-set", "30"], [/* 34 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x8c8000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e5679d000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=95291, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 95291, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7e56785000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-randr.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300[\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55568, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2150696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7e56371000
mprotect(0x7f7e5637d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7e5657d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc000) = 0x7f7e5657d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220&\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30848, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2126112, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7e56169000
mprotect(0x7f7e5616f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7e5636e000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7f7e5636e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\234\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=138016, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e56784000
mmap(NULL, 2233352, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7e55f47000
mprotect(0x7f7e55f68000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7e56167000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x20000) = 0x7f7e56167000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1738176, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3844640, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7e55b9c000
mprotect(0x7f7e55d3e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7e55f3d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a1000) = 0x7f7e55f3d000
mmap(0x7f7e55f43000, 14880, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e55f43000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14544, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7e55998000
mprotect(0x7f7e5599b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7e55b9a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f7e55b9a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\22\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20648, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e56783000
mmap(NULL, 2115888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7e55793000
mprotect(0x7f7e55798000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7e55997000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7f7e55997000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e56782000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e56781000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e56780000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7e56781700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7e55f3d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7e55b9a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7e56167000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7e5636e000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7e5657d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7e5679f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f7e56785000, 95291)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x8c8000
brk(0x8e9000)                           = 0x8e9000
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, 20) = 0
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, [20]) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="debian-mini", ...}) = 0
access("/home/myuser/.Xauthority", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/myuser/.Xauthority", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e5679c000
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7e5679c000, 4096)            = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"l\0\v\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12}, {"", 0}], 2) = 12
recvfrom(3, 0x8cd320, 8, 0, 0, 0)       = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "\1\0\v\0\0\0{\0", 8, 0, NULL, NULL) = 8
recvfrom(3, " \20\261\0\0\0 \1\377\377\37\0\0\1\0\0\24\0\377\377\1\7\0\0  \10\377\0\0\0\0"..., 492, 0, NULL, NULL) = 492
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"b\0\4\0\5\0\0\0RANDR\0\0\0", 16}], 1) = 16
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\214Y\223\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\214\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0", 12}], 1) = 12
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\20\1\5\0\t\0\0\0Backlight\0\0\0\20\1\5\0\t\0\0\0BACK"..., 40}], 1) = 40
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\3\0\0\0\0\0M\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 64
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\214\10\2\0\177\0\0\0", 8}], 1) = 8
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\5\0,\0\0\0\n\276\4\0\n\276\4\0\2\0\2\0\4\0\35\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 208
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\214\17\7\0A\0\0\0M\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 28}], 1) = 28
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1 \6\0\1\0\0\0\23\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\214\v\3\0A\0\0\0M\0\0\0", 12}], 1) = 12
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\7\0\2\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 40
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\214\17\7\0B\0\0\0M\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 28}], 1) = 28
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"+\0\1\0", 4}], 1)          = 4
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\1\t\0\0\0\0\0d\t@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

lshw -c video:

```
  *-display:0
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f0200000-f027ffff ioport:18e8(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f0000000-f00fffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0280000-f02fffff
```

Comment: What exact model of graphics card does your machine have? Which driver are you using (e.g. radeon or fglrx for ATI, nvidia or nouveau for NVidia)?

Comment: I added `lshw -c video` output, it looks like I'm using the `i915` driver? , and the graphics card is `Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller`?

Comment: [This thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04) looks like the same problem (xbacklight with an intel chip) and has solutions.

Comment: actually the echo to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` solution in that thread did work for me. would you mind adding that as an answer?

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I used the graphics card and driver information, obtained via `lshw -c video`, to narrow my search.

```
$ls /sys/class/backlight/
ideapad
intel_backlight
```

Using ideapad, which seemed to be the system default, had no effect, but using intel_backlight did:

```
$echo 1000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
1000
```

I discovered the max brigthness via:

```
$cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness 
13046
```

Later, I found a solution to get xbacklight and possibly other tools to switch to intel_backlight:

```
#in /etc/default/grub add acpi_backlight=vendor to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

$sudo update-grub
```